# Want to use datetime in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format but its type should be Datetime, is that possible in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Actually i am calling one web service's method that accepts date time parameter but in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format so Want to use datetime in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format but type should be datetime, is that possible in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Date is not stored in the form of `string` internally, the *format is just a presentation*, so you can not force the `DateTime` object of specific format. You rather convert it to the format you want. You can have DateTime as parameter of web service and convert it to the format you want or you can have `string` variable that has `DateTime` of specific format that you would convert to `DateTime` object using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**DateTime Values and their string representations**

> Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks
>   (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since
>   12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. The actual DateTime value is
>   independent of the way in which that value appears when displayed in a
>   user interface element or when written to a file. The appearance of a
>   DateTime value is the result of a formatting operation. Formatting is
>   the process of converting a value to its string representation, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime` objects in your C# code and convert when you communicate with the webservice:

```
string Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";

// getting data from the webservice
DateTime FromWebservice = DateTime.ParseExact(WebserviceDateTimeString, Format);

// sending data to the webservice
string ForWebservice = CsharpDateTime.ToString(Format);
```

Comment: webservice method's parameter says its type is Datetime and will accept date in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format. Is that possible? so my concern here is that if I convert C# date time to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format it will be string and that I cant pass wo webservice because it is expecting datetime.

Comment: A `DateTime` only has a format when presented as a `string` (see Adil's answer). Are you sure the web service does not technically accept a `string` (which presents a `DateTime`)?

Comment: yes, that is the issue, when we use parse extract/any other formatting it will return string that is not acceptable by web service method.it only require datetime type.